# Have multiple on-screen keyboards active at once - each set to input text to a specific input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, on-screen-keyboard

Bit of a tricky use case that I've run into here and am seeking some input from the community.

I'm building a pretty simple web application which will be displayed on a set of large touch screens - think 30ft wide and 6ft tall. This application has a bunch of buttons divided into separate categories - six different spaces to be exact.

We expect many users to be using this at the same time, as it will be placed in a place with heavy traffic in our office. We envision multiple users looking at different sides of the screen at the same time. When users tap a button, it will display some basic info about the button they clicked and then have a text input field to input their email address if they'd like this info emailed to them.

Multiple users could bring up this text input field in the current category they're looking at of the 6 noted above. I envision an onscreen keyboarding popping up to allow users to input their email and send off the form. Super easy if only one user is working at a time, but in this case, multiple forms could be seeking user input at the same time.

I drew up a really quick mockup to hopefully make this clearer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx6OJ.jpg

Is there any way that two separate on-screen keyboards can exist at the same time while being set to only input text to a specific text input field?

Will gladly answer any questions or input on a better way to accomplish this.

Thanks all!

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a plugin that seems to be capable of exactly this. Here's a link to the GitHub issue thread:

https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/415

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you plan on managing multiple independent views on a single screen and the multi-touch screen support but assuming you have a single page with 6 input fields I would suggest using the following keyboard extension: [jQuery Bootstrap Touch Keyboard (jQBTK)](https://www.matthewdawkins.co.uk/jqbtk/documentation.html).

This extension lets you bind each keyboard to a particular input. You may want to tweak the keyboard such that multiple keyboards can be open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I fond these results. I think this solution will help you

### **Is it possible to add multiple keyboards?**

*I checked with one virtual keyboard Mottie, it is possible to add.*

see this link: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki

### **Is there any way that two separate on-screen keyboards can exist at the same time ?**

*Possible,*
see this link: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/448